# jQuery datepicker calender issues in Firefox

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I have wrong dates showing up in my jQuery UI datepicker in some 2016 months in Firefox (Mobile & Web). For example:

March 31, 2016 is Thursday and April 1, 2016 of course is a Friday - but not on my calendar, where it shows up as a Thursday, as well. There is the same issue for May 2016.

Please see screenshots:

[image: March 2016] and [image: April 2016]

Note that I tried to use many versions of jQuery scripts but have the same issue with all of them.

Comment: There isn't a question in here... Please ask a question

Comment: there is no 31th of April, April has 30 days, something is really wrong with your question

Comment: 31th Of  March .. Edited .. Thanks 
@Jonathan I think it's an issue with Jquery UI which is wildly used all over the web .. So it's a question! what is the issue with this?

Comment: I see the screenshots but I can't reproduce in jquery ui page or jsfiddle. Impossible to reproduce. Share a working example instead of screenshots

Comment: Screenshot is not a prove, sorry. The official jQueryUI demo does not have this problem here - https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ I think there's something wrong on your computer - check: 1) disable all extensions 2) remove greasemonkey / chrome content scripts 3) run AV check

Comment: Thanks @shershen.. I am sorry to not mention that the issue I focused in Firefox browser, I edited it in the question, & I see the issue in the official jQueryUI demo in Firefox browser..

Comment: I'm using firefox and it doesn't reproduce. Disable all your addons. Impossible to reproduce

Comment: In jquery ui official website, April 1st is friday (in firefox, in chrome and even in internet explorer 5)

Comment: So it's related to my country TimeZone! As I tested the official site in 10 devices .. Mobile & PC's, and openned it by proxy too and the issue appeared, 1-4-2016 is Thursday :S

Comment: @Yossy which timezone did you have?

Comment: I had posted this before and do not see it here again, need to see your code to understand how your datepicker is configured. Would advise creating JSFiddle.net example. The TimeZone should not make a bit difference overallm but it might be the key.

Comment: I was unable to figure out what the question was.

Comment: Please create a fiddle where we can see the same error you get. If you can't replicate it, then you should dig into your code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not code issue..

> This issue has been caused by Firefox with jquery datepicker because
>   some countries had daylight saving changes on 2016-04-01, and the
>   changes is right at 00:00:00! So these countries does not have
>   00:00:00 on 2016-04-01, Firefox is confused and thinks that 00:00:00
>   is still Thursday.

And the issue has been fixed while we are in 1-4-2016 ...