# Daylight Saving Cause an issue on jQuery UI datepicker on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm having an issue with jQuery UI datepicker on Firefox.

I am working on a system based on schedules for a future date and I noticed that 2016-03-31 is Thursday, which is correct, but 2016-04-01 is also Thursday when it should be Friday!

The issue appeared on both the desktop and mobile version of Firefox, but not on other browsers.

The interesting thing is, it happens in the demos on https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ too!

Screenshot on https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ for March 2016:

[image]

Screenshot on https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ for April 2016:

[image]

As you can see, all dates on April have the wrong day of week. It is shifted by one day.

Screenshot on https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#multiple-calendars for March to May 2016:

[image]

As you can see, it's wrong in April but correct in March and May.

And, in response to [a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245848/library-issue-on-jquery-datepicker#comment60233785_36245848), yes, I'm in [Jordan, Asia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan). So?

Comment: When I look on the datepicker website it seems to be working https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: would you please test it on Firefox browser, I edited my question that the issue related to Firefox browser as it appears here too https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
so its not related to my code :S

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem on Firefox 45.0.1 on Mac.

Comment: well, I think that this issue will bother a lot of web developer if it doesn't fix ASAP

Comment: It's fine on 45.0.1 on PC

Comment: Screenshots are from 45.0.1 Firefox too..

Comment: try showOtherMonths: true, selectOtherMonths: true and check the result

Comment: Please edit your post and include the code you use for datepicker. This may be a issue from date format versus the library.

Comment: Thanks @Twisty 
But the problem is that there official site ( https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ ) have same issue on Firefox browser as I tested it in many devices :S so the issue is not related with my code

Comment: What about https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#other-months and https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#multiple-calendars ? What do you see?

Comment: Same thing @Pang , please see the new screenshot above :( Noting that  All screenshots taken from jqueryui.com

Comment: Similar report: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207234/jquery-datepicker-calender-issues-in-firefox

Comment: Maybe [it's a timezone thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207234/jquery-datepicker-calender-issues-in-firefox#comment60152430_36207234)? Which time zone are you in? What regional setting? Which country are you in? Maybe Jordan?

Comment: Yes, Asia/ Jordan,

Comment: Yes! I knew it's Jordan! [Jordan is having some Daylight Saving Time changes on 2016-04-01](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/jordan) and the change is right at 00:00:00! Apparently, Jordan does not have 00:00:00 on 2016-04-01 so Firefox is confused and thinks that 00:00:00 is still Thursday. Wow! Congratulations, Jordan, you just broke dates on Firefox!

Comment: I hope some JavaScript+DST expert can help determine if it is Firefox or jQuery UI datepicker to be blamed, and perhaps come up with a workaround.

Comment: Wowwww @Pang are you Jordanian ?? how you guessed that.. yes I forgot about this .. tommorow we have 1 hour daylight saving :D I hope it will fixed after tommorow :) You are Greate dude

Comment: There's no 31 March and only one 1 April [on this page](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2016.html), which is Jordan, and that's how I found it. I think you can test and confirm my guess by changing your regional settings on your computer.

Comment: Yeaaa when I changed timezone it Fixed.. Nice 
So you think that it will be fixed after 1-4 ... right ?

Comment: @Pang  it fixed now automatically as the time changed....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is related to my country because:

Per [@Pang comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245848/daylight-saving-cause-an-issue-on-jquery-ui-datepicker-on-firefox#comment60268123_36245848),

> [Jordan is having some Daylight Saving Time changes on 2016-04-01](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/jordan) and the change is right at 00:00:00! Apparently, Jordan does not have 00:00:00 on 2016-04-01 so Firefox is confused and thinks that 00:00:00 is still Thursday.

And the problem is fixed on the 1st of April automatically :)